# Keras Error: "ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 1]"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have been trying to create a basic predictive neural network using Keras. The purpose is to take a 12 digit input and produce a single value output. Though a combination of several tutorials I have produced the code below but am getting the error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 1]
```

I intend to add more layers/change out layers as required. My code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from numpy import genfromtxt
import csv
import pandas
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten
TRAINING_SIZE = 50000
OUTSIZE=1
REVERSE = True
INSIZE = 12 
i=[]
o=[]
with open('Dataset.csv')as f:
    csvin = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csvin:
        i.append(row[0])
        o.append(row[1])

input = np.asarray(i)
output = np.asarray(o)

print (i)
print (o)

split_at = len(i) - len(i) // 10
(i_train, i_val) = input[:split_at], i[split_at:]
(o_train, o_val) = output[:split_at], o[split_at:]

print (i_train)
print (o_train)

num_layers = 1
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.LSTM(128, input_shape=(12,1)))
model.add(layers.RepeatVector(1))
for _ in range(num_layers):
    model.add(layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="softmax"))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.summary()

epochs = 30
batch_size = 4

epochs = 30
batch_size = 32

for epoch in range(1, epochs):
    print()
    print("Iteration", epoch)
    model.fit(
        i_train,
        o_train,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        epochs=1,
        validation_data=(i_val, o_val),
    )
```

Comment: What is the shape of your input data? Is it one dimensional or more? Also, your output shape seems wrong. Right now, the output shape will be (1, 1) but since you want a single value, it should be (1,). If this is the case, try adding a flatten layer before the last dense layer.

Comment: My training data is an array: input:[326987021984  214414258186  218956485526  etc.]
output:[3 3 4 2 etc.]. I have added in the flatten layer as suggested but still get the same error

Comment: In the end this issue was solved by checking the dataset, i used the int() function to remove the ' ' that had been left when converting from a list. with open('Dataset.csv')as f:
    csvin = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csvin:
        i.append(int(row[0]))
        o.append(int(row[1]))